# vcvarsall.bat error through pip install python-docx

Tags: python, batch-file, python-3.x, docx

When running `pip install python-docx` I encounter the error message `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`.

These are basically the two solutions:

**1) Install VS2008**

**2) SET VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools**

Both I've done and the error persists.  Does anyone hold another solution?

Comment: yes 3.3 i'll try 2010.

Comment: you have to run the `setenv` command, for example: `setenv /x64 /release`. Then, when you are in the new environment, you will be able to compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Visual Studio 2010, as Python 3.3 was built with it, and therefore satisfies all dependencies needed.

1) Install VS10

2) SET VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools (assuming that the path is still the same?)

Comment: Note: I also set VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I saw that error message when installing the talib python package. I got it to work after reading this: http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?t=1761&p=2517