# How to install Numpy on Windows 8, in pyvenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, windows-8, pip

I have a virtual environment set up (Pyvenv, Python 3.4), but after executing activate.bat and the command `pip install numpy`, i get an error stating "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC` to the PATH variable, which contains the vcvarsall.bat file, yet the error still remains. What is the issue here?

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967718/vcvarsall-bat-error-through-pip-install-python-docx/22968211#22968211 Also, you might find this useful: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: You probably don't want the pain of building NumPy on Windows; it requires a Fortran compiler. You can `pip install wheel`. Use `wheel convert` on the wininst .exe to create a .whl package that you can install in virtual environments with pip. Here are the [wheel docs](http://wheel.readthedocs.org).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to compile numpy on Windows, you can just download the binaries.
The numpy team does not upload Windows binaries to pypi (an open github issue on the subject can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5479)), and you will need to download them manually from an alternative site.  This is quite easy:

1. `activate` your env and check if you have a 32 or 64 bit Python:

   ```
   (myenv) c:\mypoject\> python -c "import platform; print(platform.architecture()[0])"
   ```

   This should print `32bit` or `64bit`.
2. Download the correct numpy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and save it somewhere, (i.e. `c:\downloads`).

   For `64bit` download the `win-amd-64` versions, and for `32bit` use the `win32` versions.

   For example, for my python 2.7, I would need to download `numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl`.  **Make sure you don't change the file name! `.whl` files needs some information from the file name to be correctly identified by the pip installer!**
3. Having your env still activated, just use `pip` (which supports installing from `whl` files) to extract and install numpy:

   ```
   (myenv) c:\mypoject\> pip install c:\downloads\numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
   ```

That's it!

*Update: edited to use pip + `.whl` instead of obsolete easy_install + `.exe` packages.*

Comment: Thank you for this! Here is a helpful downloads page for all the .exe & .whl versions of Numpy, including the latest version- currently 1.9.1 http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Python3.4 then follow these steps:

1. Download "numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl" file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
2. Copy this file to C:\Python34\Scripts
3. In cmd.exe, run command as pip install "numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"

Please note:

- cp34 -> cpython3.4
- win -> windows
- amd64 -> 64-bit architecture